# Show that $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{8}{7}+\cdots +\frac{n^3}{n^2+n+1}<\frac{n(3n+5)}{6}$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction

> Show that $$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{8}{7}+\frac{27}{13}+\cdots +\frac{n^3}{n^2+n+1}<\frac{n(3n+5)}{6}$$
>
> for all natural number  $\;\forall\; n\geq 1$

what i try

$$\frac{n^3}{n^2+n+1}<\frac{n^4+n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}=n^2-n+1$$

$$\frac{n^3}{n^2+n+1}<\sum^{n}_{k=1}n^2-n+1=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n=\frac{n(n^2+2)}{3}$$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: Use $\tfrac{n^3}{n^2+n+1}=n-1+\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}$ to get an upper bound instead.

Comment: Attempting to squeeze the value by finding an upper bound is generally a good approach, but here we cannot increase the degree of the expression.

Each $\frac{n^3}{n^2+n+1}$ has degree $3-2 = 1$, and a summation of those values will give you an expression of degree $2$. Increasing the degree of each term to $2$ will result in a summation with degree $3$, which clearly already exceeds the right side.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^3}{k^2+k+1}<\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}<\frac{n(3n+5)}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

Induction will do; you need to show
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{n(3n+5)}{6}+ \frac{(n+1)^3}{(n+1)^2+n+1+1} < \frac{(n+1)(3n+8)}{6}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This is the same as $0<8n^2+24n+18$, which is easy to show.

Answer (score 0):

You are considering
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^3}{k^2+k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^n (k-1)+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2+k+1}=\frac{n(n-1)}2+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2+k+1}$$
$$k^2+k+1 > k^2 \implies \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2+k+1}<\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac {\pi^2}6$$
So, since we have now an upper bound of the lhs, it is sufficient to prove that
$$\frac{n(n-1)}2+\frac {\pi^2}6<\frac{n(3n+5)}{6}\implies \frac {\pi^2}6<\frac{4n}3$$ which is true $\forall n >0$

Answer (score 0):

Easy induction.- True for $n=1$ and
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{8}{7}+\frac{27}{13}+\cdots +\frac{n^3}{n^2+n+1}<\frac{n(3n+5)}{6}$$
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{8}{7}+\frac{27}{13}+\cdots +\frac{n^3}{n^2+n+1}+\frac{(n+1)^3}{(n+1)^2+(n+1)+1}<\frac{(n+1)(3(n+1)+5)}{6}$$ Besides
$$\frac{(n+1)(3(n+1)+5)}{6}=\frac{n(3n+5)}{6}+\frac{6n+4}{6}$$ Then by hypothesis of induction we have to prove that $\dfrac{(n+1)^3}{(n+1)^2+(n+1)+1}\le\dfrac{6n+4}{6}$ which reduces to  $$0\lt2n+1$$